# Stop the save button in dialog to close the dialog in Angular jqxScheduler

Tags: angular, stoppropagation, jqxwidgets

I'm using [jqxScheduler Angular](https://www.jqwidgets.com/angular-components-documentation/documentation/jqxscheduler/angular-scheduler-api.htm) widget in my Angular 10 App, and I need to stop the save button in Edit-dialog to close the dialog until saving process completed successfully in the back-end (WebApi), otherwise keep the dialog open for the user.
I have tried many code but it didn't work!

1. In `editDialogOpen` event, I have added:

```
      fields.saveButton.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();        
        return false;    
    });
```

2. In `AppointmentAdd` event, I have added:

```
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: The `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` are used to handle the event bubbling. It cannot stop the dialog from being closed. Please show how and where the HTTP request is made and where the dialog is closed.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelD for your reply, but there is no HTTP request, it's just a JS events.